# Problem with IFrames and SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, iframe

When having an IFrame inside SharePoint 2010, scrollbars disappears under some cirumstances depending on window size and mouse position. If holding the mouse over the address bar while refreshing the page; All HTML content dissapears from the internet explorer window. The content appears again when moving the mouse slightly. The iframe also does not respond to attributes set on the html element. For example setting the scrolling attribute to srolling="yes" should always show scrollbar, but this has no effect. This occurs on both IE9/IE8 XP/Win7. We are doing some resizing of the iframe using JS based on the users screen resolution, this worked fine for SP2007. Anyone know of any known gotchas here?

My problem looks very similar to the one described here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/show-on-iframe-div-with-jquery-ui-causes-iframe-sharepoint-page-load-to-fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never really found out why. Scraped the masterpage and it just works with a new masterpage. Probably was some html errors.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the Page Viewer Web Part instead of an IFrame? This would allow you to add the pages from within the browser and would retain the functionality. Remember adding JS to a page affects the performance of that page and takes effect as the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I would take Lori's approach and use a Page Viewer Web Part. The PVWP is essentially an iFrame, but configurable within the web part framework.

What you're probably seeing is probably not necessarily an issue with an iFrame specifically, but more the issue of the fact that the iFrame has issues with cross-browser compatibility. Using a PVWP should solve these issues since it's compatible with all of the SP supported browsers (IE7/8/9, Firefox 3.6+, Safari 4.04+).

Comment: i wonder who and why would downvote such answer... maybe it's just that answers should be more independent and comments be submitted as comments...